# how to run a python script (with Anaconda packages) on Matlab?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, matlab, anaconda, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to run a python script, which uses several Anaconda packages (python 3.7), in Matlab (i'd like to use fmincon, using an already existent python script for the evaluation of objective function and constraints.), but I can't cope with. The OS is Windows 7.

I have already read some topics on internet, and I found a couple of possible ways to deal with the issue, but none seems to work!

If I write directly in the windows cmd

```
conda activate base
cd <path to  the folder of myscript>
python <myscript>.py
```

all work. But if I write these lines in a .bat file to be invoked (system('.bat')) by matlab,
I get the following error:

```
<path to the folder of myscript> >python <myscript>.py   
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "myscript.py", line 30, in <module> 
    from polars import readPolars  # a module of mine
  File "<path to  the folder of myscript>\polars.py", line 25, in <module> 
    from numpy import triu_indices, zeros, triu, ones, empty 
  File "C:\Users\tesisti\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module> 
    from . import _distributor_init 
  File "C:\Users\tesisti\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module> 
    from . import _mklinit 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have also read that is can be due to the fact that anaconda and matlab do not have the same PATH environmental variables, so that I should add manually. However, it is not clear to me how to do.

Could someone help me? Also proposing new strategies?

Thank you.

Marco

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You basically need to add the conda Paths to the Matlab PATH environmental variables. Here is a working around in Matlab, where you should replace "pyExec" for your own path to Anaconda:

```
pyExec = 'C:\Users\chrli\anaconda3\';
pyRoot = fileparts(pyExec);
p = getenv('PATH');
p = strsplit(p, ';');
addToPath = {
   pyRoot
   fullfile(pyRoot, 'Library', 'mingw-w64', 'bin')
   fullfile(pyRoot, 'Library', 'usr', 'bin')
   fullfile(pyRoot, 'Library', 'bin')
   fullfile(pyRoot, 'Scripts')
   fullfile(pyRoot, 'bin')
};
p = [addToPath(:); p(:)];
p = unique(p, 'stable');
p = strjoin(p, ';');
setenv('PATH', p);
```

Then you can call your Python script from Matlab:

```
!conda activate base
!python myscript.py
```

You can double check the paths you need to add to the Matlab PATH by comparing the output from typing "echo %PATH%" in the cmd terminal before and after calling "conda activate base" (in the cmd).

Hope it helps. I adapt my solution based on this discussion: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/443558-matlab-crashes-when-using-conda-environment-other-than-base

Best,

Carlos.